# Getting a full address from a string

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, location

I have a spreadsheet with a names and locations. The location can be something like:

```
New York
Tokyo
San Mateo, CA
Vancouver, BC
```

Which API service (paid or free), would you advise me to use, to get the following information out of this data:

City, State, Country

Answer (score 0):

If you used Google's API, it would be a violation of service. So, you would need to look for something more tailored to what you are trying to do. Maybe try this one

https://smartystreets.com/products/single-address

Comment: This service will not work. It require a street address, as well as a city/state or zip code, if you have that, it works great, but in my case, I don't always have it

Comment: Yea, good point. Given the data you have, it may be hard for any service to accurately give you a country. Some are obvious. But, some will not be. Good luck though. Let us know what you end of doing.